# Email service Forwarding Kink

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

Why is there a difference in my email's plainTextBody when I manually forward an email to Salesforce versus auto-forwarding? Shouldn't the plainTextBody of the email always be the same?

When I manually forward the email the plainTextBody includes:

> *Congratulations, you have a new inquiry!*

When I auto-forward it I don't get this line of text at all. Does anyone have any ideas to why this might happen?

Comment: where are you forwarding the email from

Comment: @DeveloperWonk A form will be submitted by a user of Homeaway.com. Once they submit the form it is sent to our Gmail. I was testing my email service class by manually forwarding the form from Gmail to Salesforce. I developed my Regex based on this plainTextBody. Once I set up auto-forwarding from Gmail to Salesforce, the plainTextBody changed.

Comment: Did you verify that your gmail account does not have a signature defined?

Comment: I have, there is no signature defined. @DeveloperWonk